# parseInt's Radix alternative for C#

Tags: javascript, c#

int.Parse() e.t.c isnt what im looking for.

I have tried the following:

C# -> `Convert.ToInt32("ea6a85cf", 16)` results in: `-362117681`
(Test it here: http://rextester.com/UICDP93395)

JS -> `parseInt("ea6a85cf", 16)` results in: `3932849615`. (Which is what i'm looking for)
(Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/uxzrkz76/)

I also need to be able to use base 6 and 8.

Comment: Bit 31 is the sign bit. When high, it is treated as a negative number. You can use Convert.ToUint32 (ignores the sign bit) to get the desired results. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Convert.ToUint32 doesnt seem to exist?

Comment: I tested this in your rextester example. .net core, and .net framework. Been around since .net 1.1....

Comment: `Convert.UInt32`, Capital U, Capital I not `Uint32`

Comment: @PawełŁukasik That worked perfectly. Put it as answer :)

Comment: @user8549339 done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP wants the unsigned number we need to use the correct type - `UInt32` in this case. So to achieve this what we can do is:

```
uint.Parse("ea6a85cf",NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

or

```
Convert.ToUInt32("ea6a85cf", 16)
```